# Is is possible to launch a call on iPhone from desktop Chrome?

Tags: iphone, google-chrome

I know that this is possible with Android phones and desktop Chrome. But is it possible with iPhones and desktop Chrome as well?

In the Chrome window I can only see FaceTime, not actual phone:
[image: Make a call from Google Phone FaceTime]

Comment: Is Handoff/Continuity enabled between the phone and the Mac (aka does the Mac „ring“ when you get a phone call on the iPhone)?

Comment: @nohillside yes, they're enabled